# The achievement of my success was overshadowed by my elder brother's. (idiomatic?)

Tags: sentence-meaning

> The achievement of my success was overshadowed by my elder brother's.

Is this sentence idiomatic? What about this one briefly: My success was overshadowed by my elder brother's. or My success was overshadowed by that of my elder brother.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the wording is a bit awkward. You just quote the one sentence. Maybe if I saw the larger context I'd see some reason why it's important to include "the achievement". If not, I think your sentences are better than the original.